# In glade, how can I insert a widget between a parent and a child?

Tags: gtk, glade

I'm building a GUI using Glade. I realized than often, I'd need to modify the layout, for example to add a frame somewhere. However, the only way I found to achieve this was either to delete all the children of the parent, to insert the new container, and then to rebuild all the children, but it is cumbersome since I have to set again all the properties of all the children. The other way is to directly edit the XML file, but it is easy to make a mistake and to corrupt the file doing it like this. Is there a simpler way to  insert a new container between two already existing widgets (parent and child)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can cut, add your item, then paste inside it.

Comment: Well. The answer is so simple... I was searching too far away.